# Insert an array item after a specific value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I have db like;

```
{"_id" : 1 , children: ["2", "123", "5"]}
```

I want to insert an element into children array. It is easy when you know the index. $position can be used for this purpose. Like;

```
db.module_menu.update({"_id" : "1"} , 
                      {$push : {"children" : { 
                                  $each : ["12"] , $position : 1}}});
```

But lets say I don't know the position index, I know the value of element that I want to insert after.

I have `value: 12` and value that I want to insert after. `insertAfter: 2`

As a result it should be;

```
{"_id" : 1, text: "" , children: ["2","12", "123", "5"]}
```

How can I do it?

Go through each element in the children array find the index of value and by using $position, insert the value. Is it the only way to do it?

Comment: You can try with $addToSet

Comment: $addToSet might not keep the arrays order

Comment: $addToSet is just like $push? It adds to the end of the set. Am I wrong?

Comment: no, they are different in this vital point:

*$addToSet only ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the set and does not affect existing duplicate elements. $addToSet does not guarantee a particular ordering of elements in the modified set.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. There's an ancient issue to use [`$function` in update](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458) but you're only way is to read, modify and persist the array.

On the other hand if you an array of embedded documents then you can use the [`$` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/positional/).
The `$` can be used to `$set` a value in you simple array but to `$push`.

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d9570d09e01f20e254d0f3"), "a" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
> db.test.update({"_id": ObjectId("56d9570d09e01f20e254d0f3"), "a": 2},
                 {$push: {a: {$each: [2], $position: "$"}}})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 2,
        "errmsg" : "The value for $position must be a positive numeric value not a String"
    }
})
```

Comment: The example you give doesn't work. You've even included the resulting error in the output - namely that "$" resolves to a string but the position must be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to get position and update at one go, 
so in you problem you need to get position before update and pass it to query - so that means we are operating on 1:1 bassis.

Other approach is to retrieve data - perform in-place update and push full array set back to mongo